# How to design PI controllers for two cascaded control loops?

Tags: control, control-system, transfer-function, pid-controller

Let's say I have following cascaded control loops:

- inner current control loop with bandwidth \$\omega_{bw_{1}}\$ (PI controller \$R_{i_{s_{d}}}\$)
- outer flux control loop with bandwidth \$\omega_{bw_{2}} = 0.1\cdot\omega_{bw_{1}}\$ (PI controller \$R_{\psi_{r}}\$)

[image]

Let's say I have designed the gains for the PI controller of the inner current control loop in the frequency domain based on the desired phase margin.

My question is whether I can treat the inner current control loop as it has transfer function \$G_{cl}(s) = 1\$ for the purpose of the design of the outer PI controller or is it necessary to respect the actual transfer function of the inner current control loop in the outer loop design despite the fact that the inner control loop has 10 times greater bandwidth?

Comment: Steve, if you have an acceptable answer you should formally accept it or raise a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *the fact that the inner control loop has 10 times greater bandwidth?*

If the inner loop has a BW that is ten times greater than the outer loop then it's likely you can ignore the inner loop and get a decent approximation of the full transfer function by just analysing the outer loop.

But is there any real point to making this approximation given that there are so many numerical solving tools around (that make life so much easier for us) and, using them to analyse the full system is hardly any hardship at all. Just plug the diagram into a simulation tool or solver and you get the full answer. We're not living in the 1960s any more.

Comment: Would any kind person care to point out where the error is in my answer that has attracted a downvote?

Comment: As far as your answer goes ignoring the inner loop with 10 times greater bandwidth was what I was taught in school.  In industry I've commissioned a number of machines this way and they work fine.
@Steve To check your control method, Tune the outer loop with the simplified model then test the same controller with the complex model.  I suspect you'll see little performance difference.

Comment: @Andyaka, In a case the PI controller of the inner loop is designed around an OPAMP and so for the outer and the output of the outer PI will be connected directly to the non-inverting input of the inner loop. Will the phases of the two PI controllers not be affected by the cascade methode?

Comment: @learndesign how can anyone tell without a circuit. Anyway, you should ask a brand-new question.